# pandas merging of two data-frames using conditions

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, merge, dataframe

Is there a way in pandas to merge two data frames with varying lengths by using a conditional statement?
eg:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=<condition>)
```

For example assume there are two data frames, df1 and df2 with 10,000 and 15,000 objects respectively. 
I want to match common objects between the two catalogues using their x and y position. Objects should be matched between df1 and df2 such that the matched objects fall within 1m radius of each other.

Other than x and y, there is nothing common between between the two data frames.

The best I can think so far involves a for loop. I'm sure there is a faster and better way to do this?

```
delta = 1.0
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
for index, values in result.T.iteritems():
   if len(result[((result.x.iloc[:,1]-delta)<values.x.iloc[0]) & ((result.x.iloc[:,1]+delta)>values.x.iloc[0]) &
  ((result.y.iloc[:,1]-delta)<values.y.iloc[0]) & ((result.y.iloc[:,1]+delta)>values.y.iloc[0])])>0 :

        print values.id
```

Comment: Do you need to compare each value in df2 with each in df1? And what if more than one row fulfil the condition? Would that be possible?

Comment: You **cannot** join on a conditional statement with any pandas functions. You have to create keys in each dataframe that can be joined on.

Comment: @chris-sc yes for all the questions. so this should be able to identify multiple matches and return them as well.

Comment: @firelynx can you please explain how would you do this in pandas then?  Apparently there is a non-pandas function that does similarly using a kd-tree: http://docs.astropy.org/en/v0.3/coordinates/matching.html

Comment: When you need to check each value permutation, this is of O(m*n) complexity (with m and n the number of values per df). The problem you need to solve is how to get your loops more efficient, but I don't think there is a straight forward way (aka existing function) to do that in pandas.